# Как можно в gradle задать имя файла библиотеки, которое будет в сборке

Tags: gradle

Как можно в gradle задать имя файла библиотеки, которое будет в сборке.

Пример: создаём сборку zzz.war
В build.gradle есть зависимость

```
compile 'group:lib:1.0'
```

В zzz.war будет записан файл библиотеки, с именем lib-1.0.jar, мне нужно, чтобы у библиотеки было имя lib.jar

Answer (score 1):

*изменено в соотвествии с пояснениями в комментариях*

у объекта `war` есть метод [`eachFile()`, который принимает closure](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War:eachFile%28groovy.lang.Closure%29), в котором можно найти искомый файл. Найдя его можно воспользоваться его property `name`.

Comment: мне надо не war переименовать, а библиотеку внутри него

Comment: zzz.war/WEB-INF/lib/надо_переименовать_вот_это.jar

Comment: о, тогда это отличный вопрос.

Comment: пока придумал только такой вариант: в проекте для war в resourses сделал пакет: WEB-INF/lib/ и вставил в него файл библиотеки с каким надо мне именем. Библиотеку, которая указана в зависимости? принудительно исключаю с помощью exclude

Comment: так я же написал как

Comment: Простите, я не заметил, что ответ был изменён 17 марта